# Generate Radial/Ellipse/Oval/Stadium Gradient Mask (Nested For Loop)

Tags: javascript, c#, gradient, nested-for-loop

**What I'm attempting to do**

Loop through two axes and generating a shape with a width and height, either less or equal to the length of the nested for-loops, and calculate the distance from all positions to the center of that shape.

**Main Issue(s)**

1. How do I specify the width and height of an ellipse shape to draw using a nested for-loop with different dimensions to that ellipse?

For example a nested for-loop which goes for 0 to 45 in the X axis, and 0 to 100 in the Y axis but draws an ellipse with a width of 39 and a height of 90 - with the remaining difference used as padding (3 on either side, and 5 on top and bottom).

I have this half working using the EdgeOrInBounds function below, however I'm having trouble understanding why the values I'm using are giving the results they are.

Using a nested for-loop the same as above, but specifying an ellipse with a width of 30 and a height of 70 doesn't have the expected padding, it instead draws an ellipse with only one extra sprite surrounding all sides.

2. How do I calculate the distance from the center of the ellipse to the positions generated by the nested for-loop as a value between zero and one?

For example, any position outside the ellipse returns a value of zero and any position within the ellipse returns the distance scaled between zero and one from the center of the ellipse.

Similar to above, I have this half working as I can return a value of zero for all posiitons outside of the ellipse, but I do not understand how scale the distances for positions within the ellipse.

**Bonus Issue(s)**

I'm doing this on a platform where code isn't easily shareable and there are few built in functions, so I've had to create my own versions <s>stolen from</s> based on examples from the Nvidia developer site.

I have a basic understanding of some C# and JavaScript, but zero understanding of mathematical formulas.

---

**Ellipse Function(s)**

```
bool EdgeOrInBounds (Vector2 position) {
    int x = ((int) Math.Pow (position.x - center.x, 2) / (int) Math.Pow (radius.x, 2));
    int y = ((int) Math.Pow (position.y - center.y, 2) / (int) Math.Pow (radius.y, 2));

    return (x + y <= 1);
}
```

**Distance Function(s)**

```
float distance (Vector2 position) {
    return (sqrt (dot (centerPosition - position, centerPosition - position));
}

float dot (Vector2 a, Vector2 b) {
    return (a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y);
}

float sqrt (float a) {
    return (1.0 / pow (a, -0.5));
}
```

**Variables**

```
int mapWidth  = 45;
int mapHeight = 100;


Vector2 radius = new Vector2 (mapWidth - 8, mapHeight - 4);
Vector2 center = new Vector2 (mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2);
```

**Nested For Loops**

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x ++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++) {
        // Store current position to reference in a minute
        Vector2 position = new Vector2 (x, y);

        // Check if position is within bounds or lies on the edge of the ellipse
        if (EdgeOrInBounds (position)) {
            // Calculate distance from center to current position
            float dist = distance (position);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example Image**:

[image: An artistic interpretation of what I'm trying to do.]

**Closing Remarks**

I know I haven't done a good job of explaining what I'm tring to achieve, so I'd like to apologize in advance, and I'd also like to thank anyone who reads this as any help would be very much appreciated.

*Cheers*.

Comment: Hi dumbashell, you have put some questions in your code, but for the reader it is difficult to grasp what you're asking. When you have the distance, you need to decide the gray value... But it is not clear what the issue is.. you can take the center white 255 and 0 as lower limit (?) maybe I'm understanding it wrong. Could you please describe clearly (in the text) what your *question* is ?

Comment: Sorry, sure - I've attempted to make it slightly more clear what I'm trying to do but I honestly feel I lack the vocabulary and basic understanding to properly explain myself clearly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To get color shade better under control, you could use an elliptic spiral, instead of a square grid traverse. Start out with the two radii, use X=R1 * Cos(angle) and Y=R2 * Sin(angle), where you gradually decrease R1 and R2 to zero. Your loop will use polar coordinates (angle,r), see below. You are then sure of the size of your "plot" and you won't need to test distances underways. It can probably do *without* any distance function for color scaling, but I'm not sure how to do that properly.. I have included a few options.

```
        // The image is 440x240, I want ellipse in the center, margins 20 pix
        // Parameters, dependent on size and shape of elllipse

        Point pc = new Point(220,120); // pixel center
        double r1=200;                 // radius 1 margin 2x20 on 440
        double r2=100;                 // radius 2 margin 2x20 on 240

        // Covering all pixels
        int rmax = (int)Math.Max(r1,r2);

        // scaling for color
        var ravgmax = (r1+r2)/2.0;

        // Find suitable loop counts
        var nr = rmax;           // number of radius steps in loop
        var nh = 2*nr*Math.PI);  // number of angles in loop

        // Prepare initial loop displacements
        var h=0.0;
        var dr1 = r1/(nr*nh);
        var dr2 = r2/(nr*nh);
        var dh=(Math.PI*2.0)/nh;

        // The loop
        for (int i=0; i<nr; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<(int)nh; j++)
            {
                var p = new PointF((float)(pc.X+r1*Math.Cos(h)),(float)(pc.Y+r2*Math.Sin(h)));

                // vanilla shading
                // int grayscale = 255 - (int)(255 * ((r1+r2)/2.0)/ravgmax );

                // elliptical option without using distance, scale along axes
                // grayscale = 255 - (int)(Math.Abs(p.X-pc.X)*255/200+Math.Abs((p.Y-pc.Y)*255/100)/2;

                // "Distance grayscale" which is circular, not elliptical
                int grayscale = (int)(255 * floatFDistance(p,pc)/rmax);
                
                PlotF(p,grayscale); // you provide: plotpixel(PointF, int)

                r1-=dr1; r2-=dr2;
                h+=dh;
            }
        }  

    }

    float floatFDistance(PointF p1, PointF p2)
    {
        double d1 = (p1.X - p2.X); 
        double d2 = (p1.Y - p2.Y);
        return (float)(Math.Sqrt(d1 * d1 + d2 * d2));
    }
```